# Cobb Douglas Difficulty

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Show that the Cobb-Douglas production function, for Labour costs L and
>   Capital costs K, $P(L, K) = AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}$ satisfies the equation:
>
> $$L\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} + K\frac{\partial P}{\partial K} = P$$
>
> and
>
> $$L^2\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial L^2} + K^2\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial K^2} = P$$

Sorry for the bad formatting. I am a bit new to the community and I don't really know how to write the formulas nicer.

I am able to prove the first equation nicely enough:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} = \alpha A L^{\alpha-1}K^{1-\alpha},\\
L\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} = \alpha A L^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
K\frac{\partial P}{\partial K} &=& A L^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}-\alpha AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha},\\
L\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} + K\frac{\partial P}{\partial K} &=& \alpha A L^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}+AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}-\alpha AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha} = AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha} = P
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Anyway... I am trying equation number two and I have gotten down to:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
L^2\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial L^2} + K^2\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial K^2} &=& \alpha^2AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}-\alpha AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}+\alpha^2 AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}-\alpha AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}\\
&=& 2\alpha^2 AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha} - 2\alpha AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
No idea how to get to a $AL^{\alpha}K^{1-\alpha}$ from here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: As per @PerManne 's answer below, you should check your equations to be solved to see if the RHS is correct (it doesn't seem to be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, but the statement you are trying to prove is not. If you factor your last expression, you can rewrite it as $2\alpha(\alpha-1)P(K,L)$, which is not the same as $P(K,L)$ (since you presumably have $0<\alpha<1$).

Comment: Did not know that α was always between 0 and 1. Thank you for all your help.